# Python: How can I filter columns by strings without having to enter each string individually?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to analyze a dataset with enteprises of more than 80 industries regarding the respective industries. Specifically, I need a for loop or a def function with which I can summarize the following step for all industries to get a nice short code:

```
HighTech = data.loc[data['MacrIndustry'] == "High Technology", ['Value']]
```

Preferably, I would like to separate the enteprises regarding their industries into a separate DataFrame with its value.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I can't understand the problem. Could you perhaps show a sample of the version of the code that you don't like, and explain what the issue is with that version?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use `DataFrame.groupby`. The following will get you a dictionary whose keys are all the `MacrIndustry` unique values, and the values are the `Value` column (as a DataFrame) of the corresponding industry group.

```
groups = {industry: df[['Value']] for industry, df in data.groupby('MacrIndustry')}

# or just (less readable)
# groups = dict(iter(data.groupby('MacrIndustry')[['Value']]))
```

According to your example `HighTech = groups['High Technology']`.

Comment: @JonDerDon is this what you are looking for? If not, you have to provide a clearer description.